# iPhone File System

Tags: iphone, sqlite

The MyProjectName.app should be in the iPhone App structure directory as read-only, but in the project I have to join Test.sqlite and compile it, then I see the Test.sqlite in the MyProjectName.app.

I posted the project to the physical machine and inserted some data without issues. Is this the right way?

When I add the Test.sqlite and data on the iphone simulator, the Test.sqlite didn't appear to have any data. I have tried to copy the Test.sqlite to Documents. And then when I did it again, the data was displayed in the Documents's Test.sqlite. Do I need Test.sqlite to be copied to the Documents? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resources which are modified at runtime should be part of Documents directory. iPhone application creates a sandbox environment which is signed. If you try to modify any of the bundle resource, it will not allow. It works fine with simulator but not with device.

So, whatever resources are modified should be copied from bundle to documents directory.

Also, when upgrade is available, bundle is replaced with new version. However documents directory does not change. It remains same. If you want to carry any change with upgrade, you can modify data accordingly.

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

Check the Test.sqlite file is it read only or read/write.Change it into read/write.And if there is any lock for the project just uncheck it.